# Aggregate hours & minutes by day?

Tags: r, date, time

I have a dataset which has the following shape:

```
2016-04-14 23:13:33
2016-04-14 23:18:37
2016-04-15 00:32:24
2016-04-15 00:33:11
2016-04-15 00:33:20
```

What I'd like to do is to group the data in 15 minutes interval and per day, so it'd look like:

```
Date                          Count
2016-04-14  23:00-23.15        27
       .                       . 
2016-04-15  00:00 - 00:15      41
```

So the count variable would only count how many observations there are within that interval.

**UPDATE:**

I eliminated my code as I think it was confusing for the answer. So just, how would you group this data in 15min intervals preserving days? Here an example of what I mean:

```
Date                          count
2016-05-01 23:45 - 23:59       19
2016-05-02 00:00 - 00:14       276 
2016-05-02 00:15 - 00:29       328
2016-05-02 00:30 - 00:44       244
```

Any suggestion to get this "counted" data decomposed by day?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just make another column with breaks as the number of minutes in a day (60x24)?

Comment: You could just recut your data with: cut(denshours$Var1, breaks="day").

Comment: I'm sure I have to write some code just after I create hourmessages data frame in line 4, because at that point I have the data pooled by hour and day, but I want to create these 15min bins preserving the days too.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIXct variable `hourmessages$date`  contains information on both the date and time, so you just need to group by date instead of by time. Here's the modified code.

```
messages <- data.frame(created_at = c('2016-04-14 23:13:33','2016-04-14 23:18:37','2016-04-15 00:32:24','2016-04-15 00:33:11','2016-04-15 00:33:20')
)

messages$created_at <- strptime(messages$created_at,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
messages$created_at[1]
hourmessages <- data.frame(
    date=messages$created_at,
    time=format(messages$created_at, "%H:%M")
)

denshours <- with( hourmessages, table(hourmessages$date)) #Replaced 'time' with 'date'
denshours <- as.data.frame(denshours)

denshours$Var1 <- strptime(denshours$Var1,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") #Corrected date formatting
denshours$Var1 = cut(denshours$Var1, breaks="15 min")


dat.summary = aggregate(denshours$Freq ~ denshours$Var1, FUN=sum,    data=denshours)
colnames(dat.summary)[1] <- "time"
colnames(dat.summary)[2] <- "count"
```

**UPDATE**: Based on the update to your question, it looks like you want to cut your dates to "nice" breaks, such as 00:00, 15:00 instead of starting from times such as 13:00. R uses the first data point to determine the date breaks, and hence the complication. You can instead take advantage of the fact that POSIXct objects are actually numeric, and get your summary table like this:

```
messages <- data.frame(created_at = c('2016-04-14 23:13:33','2016-04-14 23:18:37','2016-04-15 00:32:24','2016-04-15 00:33:11','2016-04-15 00:33:20')
)

messages$created_at <- strptime(messages$created_at,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#This following line defines 15 minute breaks. If needed, you can replace 60*15 with the number of seconds for which you want your breaks to be defined.
messages$created_at_breaks <- as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(messages$created_at)/(60*15))*60*15,origin = '1970-01-01')

dat.summary <- data.frame(table(messages$created_at_breaks))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! It's similar to this thing but it doesn't work. I guess it has to do with arranging the data before, in the 3rd line.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for "nice" breaks.